# Magento 1.8 Zonda theme jquery conflicts

Tags: jquery, themes, magento-1.8

Installed zonda theme on Magento setup 1.8.0.0 first on local and them trying to upload theme(fresh setup) on server. On Local it works fine, when uploaded to server theme does not works. Tried cache flush, modules disabling and updating theme files. Reason I think are jQuery conflicts. I used  noConflict()  but not helpful.
Errors I get are very simple like  jQuery(...).bxSlider is not a function but bx slider scripts are correct. Any clue what I am doing wrong

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970656/my-jquery-slider-is-not-working-properly hopefully it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this already.